Efficient way to find numerical solution for intersection between a line and a Sin function
I use the Reduce command to solve for x numerically given a y. See a snippet of code
Reduce[x - y == constant + A*Sin[y] - B*Sin[x] &&  -π < x < π, Reals]

constant, A, and B are real numbers.
I specify the x range for which Mathematica should look for a solution. It works but is very slow. Repeating this takes a lot of time.
I would appreciate a more efficient way to solve this problem numerically.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Reduce isn't really suitable for numerically solving your problems. Have you tried NSolve?

A way to start is to use ContourPlot. For instance, ContourPlot[  x - y == 2 + 5 Sin[y] - Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi],    2 \[Pi]}] (after specifying A -> 5, B -> 1, and constant -> 2. Then, it is possible to extract the points from the curve and refine them using FindRoot if necessary. Here's an example of this process, and here. This is a numerical solution, but it should be pretty fast.

Thank you for both the suggestions. I had tried NSolve earlier but it had some issues earlier. I have now tried it again and it seems to work.
